Loss function not decreasing on a CNN model?
I am a creating a CNN model in order to detect emotions (I am very new to creating neural networks). The dataset I used had this structure:
DatasetName ->
train ->
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
where each number was a folder of data for a singular emotion. Each image is colored with a variety of sizes (all resized to 48x48). It has 37553 images in total.
This is the code:
# Imports
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import torchvision
import torch.nn.functional as F
import os
from skimage import io
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
from torch.autograd import Variable

# Custom dataset
class EmotionDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, root_dir, transform, train):
        self.root_dir = root_dir
        self.transform = transform
        self.train = train

        self.zero = sorted(os.listdir(os.path.join(self.root_dir, str(0))))
        self.one = sorted(os.listdir(os.path.join(self.root_dir, str(1))))
        self.two = sorted(os.listdir(os.path.join(self.root_dir, str(2))))
        self.three = sorted(os.listdir(os.path.join(self.root_dir, str(3))))
        self.four = sorted(os.listdir(os.path.join(self.root_dir, str(4))))
        self.five = sorted(os.listdir(os.path.join(self.root_dir, str(5))))
        self.six = sorted(os.listdir(os.path.join(self.root_dir, str(6))))
        self.seven = sorted(os.listdir(os.path.join(self.root_dir, str(7))))

        self.zerol = len(self.zero)
        self.onel = len(self.one)
        self.twol = len(self.two)
        self.threel = len(self.three)
        self.fourl = len(self.four)
        self.fivel = len(self.five)
        self.sixl = len(self.six)
        self.sevenl = len(self.seven)

        self.data = [self.zero, self.one, self.two, self.three, self.four, self.five, self.six, self.seven]
        self.length = self.zerol + self.onel + self.twol + self.threel + self.fourl + self.fivel + self.sixl + self.sevenl

    def __len__(self):
        return self.length

    def sub_folder(self, index):
        if index < self.zerol:
            return 0, index
        elif index >= self.zerol and index < self.zerol + self.onel:
            return 1, index - self.zerol
        elif index >= self.zerol + self.onel and index < self.zerol + self.onel + self.twol:
            return 2, index - (self.zerol + self.onel)
        elif index >= self.zerol + self.onel + self.twol and index < self.zerol + self.onel + self.twol + self.threel:
            return 3, index - (self.zerol + self.onel + self.twol)
        elif index >= self.zerol + self.onel + self.twol + self.threel and index < self.zerol + self.onel + self.twol + self.threel + self.fourl:
            return 4, index - (self.zerol + self.onel + self.twol + self.threel)
        elif index >= self.zerol + self.onel + self.twol + self.threel + self.fourl and index < self.zerol + self.onel + self.twol + self.threel + self.fourl + self.fivel:
            return 5, index - (self.zerol + self.onel + self.twol + self.threel + self.fourl)
        elif index >= self.zerol + self.onel + self.twol + self.threel + self.fourl + self.fivel and index < self.zerol + self.onel + self.twol + self.threel + self.fourl + self.fivel + self.sixl:
            return 6, index - (self.zerol + self.onel + self.twol + self.threel + self.fourl + self.fivel)
        else:
            return 7, index - (self.zerol + self.onel + self.twol + self.threel + self.fourl + self.fivel + self.sixl)


    def __getitem__(self, index):
        subfolder, mod_index = self.sub_folder(index)
        img_path = os.path.join(self.root_dir, str(subfolder), self.data[subfolder][mod_index])
        image = io.imread(img_path)

        target = torch.tensor(int(subfolder))

        if self.transform:
            image = self.transform(image)

        t = torchvision.transforms.Resize((48, 48))
        image = t(image)
        #image = image.expand(3, -1, -1)

        return image, target

# Set device
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

# Convolutional Neural Network
class ConvolutionalNeuralNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, num_classes):
        super(ConvolutionalNeuralNetwork, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=in_channels, out_channels=8, kernel_size=(3,3), stride=(1,1), padding=(1,1)) #keeps size
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=(2,2), stride =(2,2)) #cuts size in half
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=8, out_channels=16, kernel_size=(3,3), stride=(1,1), padding=(1,1)) #keeps size
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=16, out_channels=32, kernel_size=(3,3), stride=(1,1), padding=(1,1)) #keeps size
        self.conv4 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=32, out_channels=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))  # keeps size
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(64*6*6, num_classes)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu((self.conv1(x)))
        x = self.pool(x)
        x = F.relu(self.conv2(x))
        x = F.relu(self.conv3(x))
        x = self.pool(x)
        x = F.relu(self.conv4(x))
        x = self.pool(x)
        x = x.reshape(x.shape[0], -1)
        x = self.fc1(x)
        return x

# Saving model
def save_model(state, filename = "saved_model1.pth.tar"):
    print("Saving model")
    torch.save(state, filename)

# Hyperparameters
in_channels = 3
num_classes = 8
learning_rate = 0.01
batch_size = 64
num_epochs = 11

# Load Data
train_set = EmotionDataset(root_dir = os.path.join("DatasetName", "train"), transform = transforms.ToTensor(), train=True)
test_set = EmotionDataset(root_dir = os.path.join("DatasetName", "test"), transform = transforms.ToTensor(), train=False)
train_loader = DataLoader(dataset=train_set, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
test_loader = DataLoader(dataset=test_set, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False)

# Init network
model = ConvolutionalNeuralNetwork(in_channels=in_channels, num_classes=num_classes).to(device)

# Loss - cost function
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

# Learning algorithm
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr = learning_rate)

# Training
def train_model():
    print("Training Model")
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        losses = []
        for batch_idx, (data, targets) in enumerate(train_loader):
            # get data in cpu
            data = data.to(device=device)
            targets = targets.to(device=device)

            # forward
            scores = model(data)
            loss = criterion(scores, targets)

            losses.append(loss.item())

            # backward
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            loss.backward()

            # gradient descent or adam step
            optimizer.step()

        print(f"Cost at epoch {epoch} is {sum(losses) / len(losses)}")

# Testing
def check_accuracy(loader, model):
    num_correct = 0
    num_samples = 0
    model.eval()

    with torch.no_grad():
        if loader.dataset.train:
            print("Checking accuracy on training data")
        else:
            print("Checking accuracy on test data")
        for x, y in loader:
            x = x.to(device = device)
            y = y.to(device=device)
            
            scores = model(x)
            _, predictions = scores.max(1)
            num_correct += (predictions == y).sum()
            num_samples += predictions.size(0)

        print(f'Got {num_correct} / {num_samples} with accuracy {float(num_correct)/float(num_samples)*100:.2f}')

    model.train()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    # train and save model
    train_model()

    saved_model = {'state_dict': model.state_dict(), 'optimizer': optimizer.state_dict()}
    save_model(saved_model)

    check_accuracy(train_loader, model)
    check_accuracy(test_loader, model)


I have tried adjusting the learning rate, batch_size, num_epochs, but when I begin the training process, the model has an initial loss and then every consequential epoch has a very similar loss value (not decreasing at all).
I have tried using other datasets and with them, the loss function decreases but the model is very inaccurate. How could I edit this network so the loss decreases?

Short Answer:
48x48 is very likely waaaaaay too small for your problem.
Long Answer:
There are several things you can do to sanity-check your code:

Train on a very small number of images from your dataset (i.e. 10). Your CNN should be able to perfectly overfit to these training images. If you let it run for a couple epochs and your loss is not decreasing, there is something wrong with your code (you said loss decreases with other datasets so I assume this is probably not the case) or your data (see point 4.)

Increase model size. You have not provided any information on the other datasets you have tested but it's possible that the dataset you want to train on is "much more difficult" than the other datasets you have tested. For example, it's more difficult to train on imagenet (more classes, different perspectives of the same thing, etc.) than on MNIST (just a bunch of numbers basically).
Maybe you need a deeper, bigger network to be able to "understand" the complexities of your dataset.

Hyperparameters. Maybe you need to train for more samples before the loss starts to go down or you need to implement something like a learning rate scheduler (reduceonplateau or something like that).

Maybe your data is just bad. Are you sure you can actually learn something from your data? I think this is the MOST LIKELY scenario. If you have reshaped the images to 48x48 you basically have CIFAR images. This is horrible for any fine-grained detection/classification. Sure you can distinguish a horse from a plane (because of the color mainly) but you will never be able to tell the eye-color of the horse or the number of windows on the plane. Emotions are a very difficult thing to accurately predict (even for humans) and reducing the images to 48x48 is most likely trashing any signal you have.


Side notes:

When you append the losses, you should be calling .detach() first (to detach it from the computational graph).

why are you calling model.train() at the end of check accuracy?


